# How do I play this rhythm?

Tags: notation, rhythm, baroque-period, recorder, vivaldi

I am trying to play the Largo from Vivaldi's Concerto for Flautino in C Major ([RV 443](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/3/3c/IMSLP616334-PMLP943179-Vivaldi_Concerto_C-Dur,_RV_443.pdf)), but I am not sure how to time this passage in measure 4:

[image: RV 443, Largo, measure 4]

This piece is in 12/8 time, but the notes in this measure do not add up to 12 eighth notes - the passage I'm trying to play should total to 3 eighth notes, but as written, it only adds up to 18/64 (1x1/8 + 10x1/64), short of 3/8 (= 24/64). Since I am practicing with a metronome, I am trying to figure out the bpm to set here.

Looking at other versions of the sheet music, I did not see any special notation on the [facsimile](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/5/5c/IMSLP778841-PMLP943179-RV_443.pdf) version, but I found a [version](https://imslp.hk/files/imglnks/euimg/f/fe/IMSLP390547-PMLP296488-Vivaldi_-_Concerto_em_D%C3%B3_para_Piccolo_and_Strings.pdf) that indicates that this is a 10-tuple. That is the only version I have seen (on IMSLP anyway) that has the 10-tuple notation.

Looking at live performances, I notice that both [Michala Petri](https://youtu.be/DXs2q9_PMfA?si=-iz9AbKpEkLI76e2&t=277) and [Erik Bosgraaf](https://youtu.be/zqUQDwl4RuE?si=in811x4PVSbMGjuT&t=3585) play the descending portion (G-F-E-F) a little slower, and then play the ascending section (G#-A-B-C#-D-E) faster.

Is there a commonly accepted way to interpret the rhythm in an ambiguous situation like this? Since I am using a metronome, I am inclined to treat this passage like a 10-tuple just to learn the rhythm for now. But if that is the right way to read this rhythm, why didn't any of the other sheet music provide hints or any courtesy notation, since it is not immediately obvious that the notes do not add up?

Comment: The linked duplicate is somewhat different, it's solo piano music which can be played rubato. In this case there's a continuo playing eighth notes through the whole phrase, so you have to fit your notes into the time. There are ten notes to be played in the space of two eighths. You can divide them up however you want: 5+5, or do what Petri does: 4+6.

Comment: To address a part of your question that isn't duplicated over there, "why not add a 10-tuplet notation"? Well, as you've noted Vivaldi didn't, and I'd argue because he thought it *was* obvious. While tuplet markings were not anachronistic in the Baroque, unusual ones would be less common. And as to why modern editions might omit it, most likely because they're following what Vivaldi did, either as scrupulous Urtexts or as cheap print-ups.